# Need to save a single line from delete on some special condition

Tags: regex, perl

I have written a perl code which is able to search and delete a line from a file (IN_FILE) which contains "max_transition",when "direction : output" condition will satisfy. After deleting the line the code writes the modified file into a different location.

Now I need to delete the line "max_transition" when the "direction : output" condition will satisfy as well as where it will find word "timing" in that particular pin group.

IN_FILE, has output pin "HIZIBI_79", HIZIBI_78 and HIZIBI. After running the script "max_transition" line should not be deleted from pin "HIZIBI_79", HIZIBI_78", because this pin group do not have "timing". Only "max_transition" line would be deleted from pin "HIZIBI", it has a "timing" group.

Any idea how to implement it?

Output file should be look like OUT_FILE

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $inputfile = $ARGV[0]; # input lib FILE

if ($#ARGV!=0)
{
  print "USAGE :: perl max_tran_update.pl <<LIB_FILE>>  \n\n" ;
  exit(1);   
}

my $cmd = "mkdir  tmpdir;";
system ($cmd);

my $iline;
my $flag_outpin = 0;
my $out_pin_flag = 0;

open (INFILE,"<","$inputfile") || die "Can not open Input LIB File";
open (my $OPFILE,">","tmpdir/input_lib.lib") || die "Can not open Input Text File";

while ($iline = <INFILE>)
{
  chomp $iline;
  print $OPFILE "$iline\n";
  if (($iline =~m/^\s*direction\s*:\s*output\s*;/g))
  {
    $flag_outpin=1;
    while ($iline = <INFILE>)
    {
      if (($iline =~m/^\s*direction\s*:\s*input\s*;/g))
      {
        $flag_outpin=0;
      }
      if (($iline =~m/^\s*direction\s*:\s*output\s*;/g))
      {
        $flag_outpin=1;
      }
      if (($iline =~m/^\s*max_transition\s*:/g) && ($flag_outpin == 1))
      {
        $iline =~ s/$iline//g ;
      }
      else 
      {
        print $OPFILE "$iline";
      }
    }
  }
}      
close INFILE;
close $OPFILE;
```

IN_FILE

```
  cell (lib_1) {
    dont_use : true ;
    dont_touch : true ;
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 12 ;
    }  
    pin ("HIZIBI_79")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 3 ;
    }              
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("HIZIBI_78")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 34 ;
      capacitance : 34 ;
    }            
    pin ("HIZIBI")    {
      direction : output ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 20;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  
      }  
    }
  }
```

OUT_FILE

```
  cell (lib_1) {
    dont_use : true ;
    dont_touch : true ;
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 12 ;
    }  
    pin ("HIZIBI_79")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 3 ;
    }              
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("HIZIBI_78")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 34 ;
      capacitance : 34 ;
    }            
    pin ("HIZIBI")    {
      direction : output ;
      clock : true ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you check your required output again?. the timing() is not deleted..

Comment: "max_transition" line must be deleted not the timing block. "max_transition" must be deleted in which pin group the code will find timing group. please see, from pin HIZIBI, max_transition is deleted.

Comment: Your simple solution "read a line, don't print it when conditions are met" won't work with your new requirement, as `timing(` occurs after the line you want to delete. You'll have to rewrite your code to read one whole `pin(..) { ... }` section in, decide which lines to delete and then dump it to the output. As you have several block-type statements you will either need to count the open brackets or write a real parser for the given syntax.

Comment: Code is far easier to read if it is indented properly. I've just fixed that for the code in this question. Please do it yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets a lot easier if you parse the file to deal with one `pin { ... }` section at a time. This code seems to do the trick, but it's probably fragile and might well break on more complex input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# $counter will contain the number of unmatched { characters
# we have seen. If it's a positive number then we are in a
# pin section and we won't output anything until we get to
# the end of that section.
my $counter;
# Contains the contents of our current pin section.
my $pin = '';

# Read a line at a time from STDIN
while (<>) {
  # If we're not in a pin block, then
  # just print the line.
  if (!$counter and !/\bpin\b/) {
    print;
    next;
  }

  # Increment $counter by the number of { characters in the line
  $counter += tr/{/{/;
  # Decrement $counter by the number of } characters in the line
  $counter -= tr/}/}/;

  # Append the current line to $pin
  $pin .= $_;

  # If $counter is 0 then we've just got to the end of a pin
  # block. The text of that block will be in $pin.
  if (!$counter) {
    # If $pin contains "directions : output" and "timings"...
    if ($pin =~ /direction\s*:\s*output/ and $pin =~ /timing\s*/) {
      # ... then remove the "max_transitions" line from $pin
      $pin =~ s/\s*max_transition\s*:.*\n//;
    }
    # Print the current $pin section
    print $pin;
    # And reset $pin to start the next section.
    $pin = '';
  }
}
```

I've also written this as a Unix filter. That is, it reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT`. This is more flexible than hard-coding filenames. You would run it like this:

```
$ my_pin_filter < in_file > tmpdir/input_lib.lib
```

Comment: This is the best answer @Dave Cross. I believe you have done the best way it should be. No it is not " fragile ", the code is meeting every conditions which I did not mention here. Thank you Sir :)

Comment: I am very very sorry, I should  click on the check mark beside the answer. Just now I did it. 
Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command line Perl

```
 perl -0777 -ne ' s/(pin\s*\(".+?"?\)\s+\{.+?\})/$x=$1;if($x=~m!timing\s*\(\)! and $x=~m!direction : output!){$x=~s!^\s*max_transition.+?\n!!mg};$x/gse ; print ' anny_in.txt
```

**Results:**

```
 cell (lib_1) {
    dont_use : true ;
    dont_touch : true ;
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 12 ;
    }
    pin ("HIZIBI_79")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 3 ;
    }
    pin ("HIZIBI_IN_1") {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
      capacitance : 1 ;
    }
    pin ("HIZIBI_78")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      min_capacitance : 34 ;
      capacitance : 34 ;
    }
    pin ("HIZIBI")    {
      direction : output ;
      clock : true ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Dear stack0114106, 
After running the command I am getting "timing: Event not found" from command line.

Comment: @anny..no it worked for me..anny_in is the input file..  please try again

Comment: Dear stack0114106, I tried several times, but still getting the same issue. Is it due to we are using different OS version? I am using it into CentOS 6.7.

Comment: im running it in cygwin.. can you check if ````\r```` is present?.. if so remove that and try again?

Comment: \r is not present

Comment: Dear stack0114106, can you pleas post which perl verson you are using, I am using "This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi ". I believe the version differences can create the issue.

Comment: I did try this in our Enterprise perl ````This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi```` and got the same output.. Are you pasting the entire command in a single line or not ?

Comment: Yes, I copied the whole perl command and paste it in a single line in command prompt. Can not figure out, where the actual issue at my end.

Comment: I use the same command for upgraded perl compiler and it is executing the way it should be :) 
Thanks a lot for your support  stack0114106

Comment: anny!.. great that it worked for you now..I was wondering what could have went wrong!.. please consider accepting the answer

Comment: What is the point in posting this as a cryptic command line script? Wouldn't it make more sense to post it as a complete program? With comments explaining how it works.