# Can't create unknown regex: $RE{some}{pattern}

Tags: regex, perl

I have a code here which throws the following error - "Can't create unknown regex: $RE{some}{pattern} " when I am running it using module Regexp::Common.

The objective of the code is to read a file,search for a string and execute 2 conditions. First condition: if the function timing is present for a pin, then search for string "direction : output", find consecutive lines below and delete the string containing "max_transition :" and if the function timing is not present, then do nothing. If timing function is present and the  search string is "direction : input" , then do nothing. This needs to be done multiple times in the file. When I am using the line if( $RE{some}{pattern}->matches($str) )  , the code throws the above error. Please help me solve this error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use Regexp::Common;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
my $str = "direction : output";
open (INFILE,"<","$inputfile") || die "Can not open Input LIB File";
open (my $OPFILE,">","tmpdir/input_lib.lib") || die "Can not open Input Text File";
    sub do_something_with {
        my $string=shift;
        if( $RE{some}{pattern}->matches($str) )  {
             if ($string =~ m{timing +($RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'} +$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'})})  { # has a timing group
            $string =~ s{^.*max_transition.*\r?\n}{}m;
            }
        }
    }
        return $string;
    }
        local $/;
my $string=<INFILE>;
$string=~ s{pin +($RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'} +$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'})}{"pin ".do_something_with($1)}ge;
print $OPFILE "$string";
close INFILE;
close $OPFILE;
```

My input is :

```
cell (lib) {
    dont_use : true ;
    dont_touch : true ;
    pin ("A") {
      direction : input ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("B")    {
      direction : output ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 10;
    }              
    pin ("C") {
      direction : input ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("D")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
    }            

    pin ("E")    {
      direction : output ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 20;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  

    pin ("F")    {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 20;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  
      }  
    }
```

My intended output is :

```
cell (lib) {
    dont_use : true ;
    dont_touch : true ;
    pin ("A") {
      direction : input ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("B")    {
      direction : output ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 10;
    }              
    pin ("C") {
      direction : input ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      max_transition : 1 ;
    }  
    pin ("D")    {
      direction : output ;
      max_transition : 10;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
    }            

    pin ("E")    {
      direction : output ;
      clock : true ;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  

    pin ("F")    {
      direction : input ;
      clock : true ;
      max_transition : 20;
      related_power_pin : VDD ;
      related_ground_pin : VSS ;
      timing () {
        cell_fall (into_f1) {
          index_1("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          index_2("1,2,3,4,5") ;
          values("13, 13, 14, 16, 18",\
                 "13, 14, 15, 16, 19",\
                 "14, 15, 16, 17, 20",\
                 "15, 15, 16, 18, 20",\
                 "15, 16, 17, 18, 21") ;
        }  
      }  
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the code gets stuck"? Can you please [edit] your question and elaborate?

Comment: Didn't we already give you a [solution to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55352667)?

Answer (score 3):

You have copy/pasted examples from the [Regexp::Common documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common#OO-interface-and-inline-matching/substitution), but misunderstood what they mean.

> The patterns returned from %RE are objects, so rather than writing:
>
> ```
> if ($str =~ /$RE{some}{pattern}/ ) {...}
> ```
>
> you can write:
>
> ```
> if ( $RE{some}{pattern}->matches($str) ) {...}
> ```

The `{some}{pattern}` here is a placeholder for your actual pattern. I believe the one you want is `$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'}`, which you've correctly used literally a line further down.

Comment: I believe quite a bit of your code is copy/pasted and you might not fully understand what all of it does. You are mixing global and lexical filehandles for reading and writing, which tells me you likely found each individual one somewhere else and have pieced this together from different sources. That's fine of course. If you need more help, please ask.

Comment: Could you show me how to create my own pattern then? This is because $RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()' isn't working to check for "direction:output" string.